# How can I format numbers in order to have always two digits?

Tags: swift

I am creating a countdown timer that shows hours:minutes:seconds.

The function I have works however, it returns the values as 1 digit if the number is less than 10. (ex. 2:3:15)

How can I format my function in order to have always two digits?

I am looking for a result like: 02:03:15

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
        return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
    }
```

Comment: thank you found the solution

Comment: use `"%02d:%02d:%02d"` as formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively using `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
lazy var dateComponentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    return formatter
}()

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Int) -> String {
    let hourPad = seconds < 36000 ? "0" : "" // add 0 in front if less than 10 hours
    return hourPad + dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: seconds)!
}

secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(3602) // 01:00:02
```

Since `DateComponentsFormatter` does not pad the hours automatically with `zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad`, you have to add that "manually".
The formatter itself is declared as a lazy computed property to avoid repetitive re-instantiation.

Comment: thank you a lot. Much better approach and clean code